# Silverstripe Data Object specify table name

Tags: php, orm, silverstripe

Is there a way to override the default behavior of SS Data Objects such that when I assign a static `$table_name property` to my DataObject the dev/build does not create a table name with the DO name like it normally does?

For example I have this very small Data Object

```
<?php
    class SalesRep extends DataObject {

        private static $table_name = 'tbl_users';

    }
```

I am trying to prevent creation of table salesrep on dev/build and also I would like the ORM to know that when I do a `$Model->write()`; I'm writing to the table `tbl_users` instead of table salesrep

Comment: `table_name` is only available with SilverStripe 4, which is still in alpha stage. So maybe you're using another version of SilverStripe 4, or the feature is not properly implemented (yet?)

Answer (score 3):

This is currently not possible with SilverStripe 3.x. SilverStripe uses the "convention over configuration" principle and the database tables always have the same name as the related DataObject.

However, in SS4, with namespacing, you'll be able to define a tablename in your config. As @bummzack already noted, this is currently in alpha.

However, you might try and overwrite DataObject's `getBaseTable()`, which method like:

```
/**
 * Get the name of the base table for this object
 */
public function baseTable() {

    return 'tbl_users';
}
```

but i doubt it'll work without problems, cause in other places the baseTable property is - again - generated out of the class names.

Comment: I am using Silverstripe 3.2. Now I see why even `baseTable()` is not working. Silverstripe is a really good framework but severely lacking in some areas.

Answer (score 1):

This is part of using the ORM that is within SilverStripe and can take some getting used to.  I would perhaps look at this in two different ways...

1) If your goal is to present a certain name to the user, but have a different table name then the solution is to use *singular_name* and *plural_name* and then you are free to name the DataObject however you wish...

```
class tbl_users extends DataObject {

   private static $singular_name        = 'Sales Rep';
   private static $plural_name      = 'Sales Reps';

   ...
}
```

..remember the whole point of the ORM is that the PHP class defines the table and it would make sense to keep the table name the same as you'd like to use in the code.

2) If it absolutely has to be a specific table then you can specify it as an external table/content and one of the following solutions might suit you best... ["Save to external Table"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32582566/silverstripe-save-data-to-external-table), ["External Content Module"](https://github.com/nyeholt/silverstripe-external-content) or ["External Data Module"](https://github.com/axyr/silverstripe-externaldata)